# Como executar apenas um if sem entrar no outro no PHP

Tags: php, html, if

Tenho dois `if` paralelos e preciso entrar em um OU em outro, não nos dois. Só que em função de eu estar dentro de um `while` com o primeiro `if`, eu não consegui colocar apenas um `else`, tendo que fazer outro `if` fora do `while`. Então, cada vez que ele entra na condição do primeiro if ele acaba entrando também na do segundo.

Tem algo que eu possa colocar que se eu entre no primeiro ele pule o segundo?

Aqui está o código:

```
while ($arrayBancas = mysql_fetch_array($oBanca->retorno())){
   if (date('Y-m-d', strtotime($arrayBancas['dataHora'])) == $data->format('Y-m-d')) {
       echo '<div class="panel panel-default">';
          echo '<div class="panel-heading">';
             echo '<a href=""><center><strong>--:--</strong></center></a>';
          echo '</div>';    
          echo '<div class="panel-body">';    
             echo '<h6>';
               echo '<strong>'.$arrayBancas['trabalho'].'</strong><br>';
               echo '<strong>Orientador:</strong>'.$arrayBancas['orientador'].'<br>';   
               echo '<strong>Banca:</strong><br>';
               echo '<strong>Sala:</strong>'.$arrayBancas['sala'].'<br>';
             echo '</h6>';
          echo '</div>';
       echo '</div>';
     }
}
    if (date('Y-m-d', strtotime($arrayBancas['dataHora'])) != $data->format('Y-m-d')) {
       echo '<div class="panel panel-default">';
           echo '<div class="panel-heading">';
               echo '<a href=""><center><strong>--:--</strong></center></a>';
           echo '</div>';    
           echo '<div class="panel-body">';    
               echo '<h6>';
                   echo '<strong>----------</strong><br>';
                   echo '<strong>Orientador:</strong><br>'; 
                   echo '<strong>Banca:</strong><br>';
                   echo '<strong>Sala:</strong><br>';
               echo '</h6>';
           echo '</div>';
       echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Veja o que você deseja porque eu entendi uma coisa, o Sergio entendeu outra. As duas respostas são radicalmente diferentes, uma das duas não responde o que você deseja. De fato a pergunta está confusa. Tente explicar melhor. O Sergio apagou a dele mas não sei se não é a dela que está certa.

Comment: Pois é, não cheguei a ver, agora que entrei aqui e só tava a sua resposta mas era isso mesmo, na mosca!! Valeu!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A forma mais fácil é usar uma *flag*:

```
$entrou = false;
while ($arrayBancas = mysql_fetch_array($oBanca->retorno())){
   if (date('Y-m-d', strtotime($arrayBancas['dataHora'])) == $data->format('Y-m-d')) {
       echo '<div class="panel panel-default">';
          echo '<div class="panel-heading">';
             echo '<a href=""><center><strong>--:--</strong></center></a>';
          echo '</div>';    
          echo '<div class="panel-body">';    
             echo '<h6>';
               echo '<strong>'.$arrayBancas['trabalho'].'</strong><br>';
               echo '<strong>Orientador:</strong>'.$arrayBancas['orientador'].'<br>';   
               echo '<strong>Banca:</strong><br>';
               echo '<strong>Sala:</strong>'.$arrayBancas['sala'].'<br>';
             echo '</h6>';
          echo '</div>';
       echo '</div>';
       $entrou = true;
    }
}
if (!$entrou) {
   echo '<div class="panel panel-default">';
       echo '<div class="panel-heading">';
           echo '<a href=""><center><strong>--:--</strong></center></a>';
       echo '</div>';    
       echo '<div class="panel-body">';    
           echo '<h6>';
               echo '<strong>----------</strong><br>';
               echo '<strong>Orientador:</strong><br>'; 
               echo '<strong>Banca:</strong><br>';
               echo '<strong>Sala:</strong><br>';
           echo '</h6>';
       echo '</div>';
   echo '</div>';
}
```

Por outro lado talvez você queira outra coisa (que eu não pude imaginar porque era fácil demais):

```
while ($arrayBancas = mysql_fetch_array($oBanca->retorno())){
    echo '<div class="panel panel-default">';
    echo '  <div class="panel-heading">';
    echo '    <a href=""><center><strong>--:--</strong></center></a>';
    echo '  </div>';    
    echo '  <div class="panel-body">';    
    echo '    <h6>';
    if (date('Y-m-d', strtotime($arrayBancas['dataHora'])) == $data->format('Y-m-d')) {
        echo '      <strong>'.$arrayBancas['trabalho'].'</strong><br>';
        echo '      <strong>Orientador:</strong>'.$arrayBancas['orientador'].'<br>';   
        echo '      <strong>Banca:</strong><br>';
        echo '      <strong>Sala:</strong>'.$arrayBancas['sala'].'<br>';
    } else {
        echo '       <strong>----------</strong><br>';
        echo '       <strong>Orientador:</strong><br>'; 
        echo '       <strong>Banca:</strong><br>';
        echo '       <strong>Sala:</strong><br>';
    }
    echo '    </h6>';
    echo '  </div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Algorithm/ConditionalHTML.php).

Eu tive que reorganizar o código para poder entender. Dá pra simplificar mais ainda mas talvez você não entenda.